# I am getting the error firestore.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
// src/firebase.js

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'MY_AUTH_DOMAIN',
  projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'MY_STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
  appId: 'MY_APP_ID',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export const bookmarksCollection = firestore.collection('bookmarks');

export default app;
```

I am getting the error firestore.collection is not a function error

Let me know is that the problem that i didn,t made the collection in firestore or is it any other issue if it is help me fix that

Comment: please try firestore().collection(“bookmarks”)